# Derive a vertex representation of a permutohedron from its linear-inequalities form

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes

Let us define the $n$-permutohedron $P_n$ as the set of all $x\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \binom{n{+}1}{2}\ \ \ \land\ \ \ \forall\,\text{nonempty}\ S\subsetneq\mathbb{N}_n\colon\ \sum_{i\in S} x_i \le \binom{n{+}1}{2} - \binom{n+1-\lvert S\rvert}{2}.$$

I'd like to determine the set of vertices of $P_n$. (Hereby, a vertex of a polyhedron is a point $x$ such that $\{x\}$ is a face.) The set of vertices is supposed to be

$$\left\{\left(\sigma(i)\right)_{i=1}^n\,\middle|\, \sigma:\mathbb{N}_n\to\mathbb{N}_n\ \text{is a permutation}\right\},$$

but I'm missing the proof that this set is actually the set of vertices from the aforementioned definition of $P_n$.
What would be the easiest low-level, step-by-step, Bourbaki-like way to do this proof? If failed to find a derivation online. Literature references are very welcome.

Comment: Find intersections of maximal numbers of hyperplanes determined by the equalities corresponding to these inequalities.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that your set of inequalities is $S_n$-invariant, hence your polytope is, hence your set of vertices is. So it's enough to understand the case $x_1 \leq \ldots \leq x_n$.

Now you don't need to think about general $S$; for each $|S|$ the tightest inequality comes from $S = [n-|S|+1,n]$ a terminal interval. The $|S|=n$ inequality is actually your first equality, so $n-1$ inequalities remain, which is the dimension. If you impose those as equalities (as მამუკა ჯიბლაძე suggests), and take their differences, you get $x_i = i$ for each $i$.